# Combine two dataframes cell-wise by a third func mapping dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider `df_a` and `df_b` where

1. `df_a.index == df_b.index`
2. `df_a.columns == df_b.columns`
3. `df_a.dtypes == df_b.dtypes == float`

Now I have <s>another dataframe</s>, `op`, a `pd.Series` where

1. `op.index == df_a.index`
2. `op.shape[0] == 1`, ie, `op` is a vector (`pd.Series`) and each row (element) is of the form `operator(a: float, b: float) -> bool`

I want to achieve `df_a <op> df_b`, ie, each cell of `a` and `b` must be compared using `operator` and the result `df_op` should have shape identical to `df_a` and `df_b`.

EDIT: here's a minimal example of what I want to achieve:

```py
from operator import gt, lt

from numpy import nan


df_a = pd.DataFrame({'CAT': {'marketCapTTM': 33.39465142383641, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 81.05974830429687, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 5.221448839220668, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 12.643766377289978, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 34.43608541699433, 'dividendYieldTTM': nan, 'earningsYieldTTM': nan, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': nan, 'revenuePerShareTTM': nan, 'ROE': 1.6988369839109645, 'enterpriseValueTTM': nan, 'debtToEquityTTM': 2.8755516480792895, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': 11.318374596873056, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': 3.296170855785674}, 'KO': {'marketCapTTM': 16.19804346060541, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 13.520338019619583, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 1.4791311212081197, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 5.3419302547561, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 44.63557734663028, 'dividendYieldTTM': 33.504017101396435, 'earningsYieldTTM': nan, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': 11.13681987256062, 'revenuePerShareTTM': 27.529850258482526, 'ROE': nan, 'enterpriseValueTTM': 39.04183307431106, 'debtToEquityTTM': nan, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan}, 'DIS': {'marketCapTTM': 10.350071360171354, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 92.3074779922466, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 2.489890153696122, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 16.84014609959747, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 29.892799370630662, 'dividendYieldTTM': 7.276474595382507, 'earningsYieldTTM': 38.39492540086857, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': 4.0478509770567825, 'revenuePerShareTTM': 9.658344729379438, 'ROE': 45.11442699745053, 'enterpriseValueTTM': nan, 'debtToEquityTTM': nan, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan}})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'CAT': {'marketCapTTM': 29.887325295389743, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 31.83889927186704, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 27.134180811823384, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 10.849504294710492, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 20.887572108177135, 'dividendYieldTTM': nan, 'earningsYieldTTM': nan, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': nan, 'revenuePerShareTTM': nan, 'ROE': 25.230080182979187, 'enterpriseValueTTM': nan, 'debtToEquityTTM': 50.175058716128994, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': 39.21225330073516, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': 25.26732056715597}, 'KO': {'marketCapTTM': 35.57854672737116, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 52.098967463491945, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 22.943564836479496, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 7.022975757514489, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 4.90371517588241, 'dividendYieldTTM': 2.1442957674601324, 'earningsYieldTTM': nan, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': 64.68716099305611, 'revenuePerShareTTM': 9.960264176165484, 'ROE': nan, 'enterpriseValueTTM': 11.32154660489711, 'debtToEquityTTM': nan, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan}, 'DIS': {'marketCapTTM': 5.935286159527827, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': 17.255701701169624, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': 37.50072163718486, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': 14.009615847232455, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': 17.91946520859328, 'dividendYieldTTM': 2.2431492946899283, 'earningsYieldTTM': 47.90549865927282, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': 38.315078361282225, 'revenuePerShareTTM': 1.7762807962951885, 'ROE': 44.23368129207099, 'enterpriseValueTTM': nan, 'debtToEquityTTM': nan, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': nan}})
op = pd.Series({'marketCapTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'bookValuePerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'netIncomePerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'dividendYieldTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'earningsYieldTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'priceToSalesRatioTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'revenuePerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'ROE': <built-in function gt>, 'enterpriseValueTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'debtToEquityTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>, 'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM': <built-in function gt>})

print(df_a.shape, df_b.shape, op.shape, type(df_a.shape), type(df_b.shape), type(op.shape), df_a.columns, op.index)
```

Stats are as follows:

```bash
(14, 3) (14, 3) (14,) <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> Index(['CAT', 'KO', 'DIS'], dtype='object') Index(['marketCapTTM', 'shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM',
       'tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM', 'bookValuePerShareTTM',
       'netIncomePerShareTTM', 'dividendYieldTTM', 'earningsYieldTTM',
       'priceToSalesRatioTTM', 'revenuePerShareTTM', 'ROE',
       'enterpriseValueTTM', 'debtToEquityTTM', 'freeCashFlowPerShareTTM',
       'operatingCashFlowPerShareTTM'],
      dtype='object', name='indicator')
```

Desired output is generated (currently) using:

```py
signals = _funcs.reset_index().apply(
    lambda row: row.direction(
        df_a.loc[row.indicator],
        df_b.loc[row.indicator]
    ),
    axis=1
).set_index(_funcs.index)
```

and results in:

```bash
    CAT KO  DIS
indicator           
marketCapTTM    True    False   True
shareholdersEquityPerShareTTM   True    False   True
tangibleBookValuePerShareTTM    False   False   False
bookValuePerShareTTM    True    False   True
netIncomePerShareTTM    True    True    True
```

Comment: Can you add example of data, e.g. 2x2 DataFrames - `df_a, df_b` with `op` with expected ouput?

Answer (score 1):

If `op` is `Series` you can create list of DataFrames and pass to [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with broadcasting:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')

op = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['+','-','*','/'], size=10), index=df1.index)
print (df1)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.321988  0.890422  0.588052  0.126596
1  0.141341  0.467896  0.022090  0.727275
2  0.524387  0.544935  0.456373  0.501382
3  0.394469  0.151172  0.360875  0.162077
4  0.337959  0.180323  0.390991  0.035648
5  0.564862  0.203461  0.320604  0.376564
6  0.184054  0.103952  0.454927  0.195864
7  0.378525  0.930532  0.760160  0.770764
8  0.596701  0.791621  0.810338  0.980557
9  0.884785  0.109801  0.819711  0.307613

print (df2)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.261495  0.405724  0.553420  0.625526
1  0.078760  0.972283  0.411311  0.721664
2  0.663287  0.218225  0.187173  0.729779
3  0.863313  0.391720  0.110048  0.912792
4  0.357006  0.412962  0.183550  0.585990
5  0.855671  0.789681  0.087842  0.932993
6  0.499951  0.364257  0.483606  0.515225
7  0.994643  0.753403  0.365820  0.611373
8  0.419611  0.091677  0.534854  0.340764
9  0.018341  0.603453  0.921806  0.281364
```

---

```
print (op)
0    -
1    +
2    -
3    +
4    /
5    *
6    *
7    +
8    +
9    *
dtype: object
```

---

```
v = [df1.add(df2), df1.sub(df2), df1.mul(df2), df1.div(df2)]

arr = op.to_numpy()[:, None]
m = [(arr == '+'),(arr == '-'),(arr == '*'),(arr == '/')]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select(m, v), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.060494  0.484699  0.034632 -0.498930
1  0.220101  1.440179  0.433401  1.448939
2 -0.138900  0.326710  0.269201 -0.228397
3  1.257782  0.542893  0.470923  1.074869
4  0.946647  0.436658  2.130166  0.060834
5  0.483336  0.160670  0.028163  0.351331
6  0.092018  0.037865  0.220006  0.100914
7  1.373169  1.683935  1.125980  1.382137
8  1.016312  0.883298  1.345192  1.321321
9  0.016228  0.066260  0.755614  0.086551
```

If `op` is `DataFrame`:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')

df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['+','-','*','/'], size=(10,4)), index=df1.index)
print (df3)
   0  1  2  3
0  -  +  -  +
1  /  *  *  +
2  +  *  *  *
3  -  -  -  /
4  *  /  +  /
5  +  *  +  *
6  +  -  *  /
7  -  +  /  -
8  *  /  -  *
9  -  *  -  *
```

---

```
v = [df1.add(df2), df1.sub(df2), df1.mul(df2), df1.div(df2)]
m = [(df3 == '+'),(df3 == '-'),(df3 == '*'),(df3 == '/')]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.select(m, v), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (df)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.060494  1.296146  0.034632  0.752123
1  1.794576  0.454927  0.009086  1.448939
2  1.187675  0.118919  0.085421  0.365898
3 -0.468845 -0.240548  0.250827  0.177562
4  0.120653  0.436658  0.574541  0.060834
5  1.420532  0.160670  0.408447  0.351331
6  0.684005 -0.260305  0.220006  0.380152
7 -0.616118  1.683935  2.077962  0.159391
8  0.250382  8.634920  0.275484  0.334139
9  0.866444  0.066260 -0.102095  0.086551
```

EDIT: If need compare by operators:

```
np.random.seed(2023)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4)).add_prefix('col')

op = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['>','!=','=='],size=10))


print (df1)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.321988  0.890422  0.588052  0.126596
1  0.141341  0.467896  0.022090  0.727275
2  0.524387  0.544935  0.456373  0.501382
3  0.394469  0.151172  0.360875  0.162077
4  0.337959  0.180323  0.390991  0.035648
5  0.564862  0.203461  0.320604  0.376564
6  0.184054  0.103952  0.454927  0.195864
7  0.378525  0.930532  0.760160  0.770764
8  0.596701  0.791621  0.810338  0.980557
9  0.884785  0.109801  0.819711  0.307613

print (df2)
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0  0.261495  0.405724  0.553420  0.625526
1  0.078760  0.972283  0.411311  0.721664
2  0.663287  0.218225  0.187173  0.729779
3  0.863313  0.391720  0.110048  0.912792
4  0.357006  0.412962  0.183550  0.585990
5  0.855671  0.789681  0.087842  0.932993
6  0.499951  0.364257  0.483606  0.515225
7  0.994643  0.753403  0.365820  0.611373
8  0.419611  0.091677  0.534854  0.340764
9  0.018341  0.603453  0.921806  0.281364
```

---

```
print (op)
0    !=
1     >
2    !=
3     >
4    ==
5    ==
6     >
7     >
8    ==
9    ==
dtype: object
```

---

```
arr = op.to_numpy()[:, None]

df = ((df1.eq(df2) & (arr == '==')) | 
      (df1.gt(df2) & (arr == '>')) |
      (df1.ne(df2) & (arr == '!=')))
      
print (df)
    col0   col1   col2   col3
0   True   True   True   True
1   True  False  False   True
2   True   True   True   True
3  False  False   True  False
4  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False
6  False  False  False  False
7  False   True   True   True
8  False  False  False  False
9  False  False  False  False
```

Comment: `op` should not be add, mul, sub, div but rather gt, lt, eq,... Check the signature. `op(a, b)` returns a boolean.

Comment: @Corralien - added EDIT to answer.

Comment: While this seems like a _clean_ approach, these dataframes are potentially going to be very large, so the motivation behind asking this question was to avoid non-vectorized `.apply`. However, you have `v` which is (arguably) trading off some computation for a large amount of memory

Comment: @PratikK. - What is `print (df1.shape)` ? If use `.apply` solution it is not slow?

Comment: `df1.shape` will be in the range of `(200+, 4000)` or so